# Will I break website if I scrape 75,000+ products at once? It'll take 2 days to download

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

*Update*: I built the web scraper, ran some initial tests and it looks like **I'll need over 50 hours to scrape** everything!! I'm shocked that it'll take so long. If I just leave my laptop running for that period will I break/slow down their website and can I get in trouble for this?

I’m just getting into web scraping and want to make sure I don’t hurt the website. I’m planning on going through several hundred pages using beautiful soup, following about 100 links on each search results page and downloading a total of over 75,000 descriptions (text only) for the products. This is a big site, but I’d still like to make sure I don’t accidentally DDoS them. Any suggestions, i.e. what time delays (if any) I need to add or what period of time I should stretch this out over?

Comment: Who knows?  It could be 75,000+ products on a Pentium III in someone's basement, hooked up to DSL.  It could be all on S3 backed by a six-figure monthly IT budget.

Comment: Only one way to find out!

Comment: I suggest a 5 sec sleep inbetween requests

Comment: Nah, these guys are big. You could compare them to a government agency's website.

Comment: If it's a big site, it's likely they will throttle your requests. That being said, even if they don't throttle you, your machine (assuming you're not using a botnet) is very unlikely to be able to DDOS a decently sized site, even if you wanted to.

Comment: You won't unless you will use multiple servers because DDoS means **Distributed** Denial of Service.
But, of course, it depends on their QoS and you may monitor your requests for execution time and any errors.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Just wanted to make sure I don't hurt the website or end up in any trouble.

Comment: How is this primarily opinion based? The answer is no, you cannot DDoS with one IP/client (nothing indicates OP is using multiple).

Comment: More than likely, they will detect the high volume of traffic (your scraping) and ban your IP address.  good luck

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff. Any thoughts on why it's taking so long to scrape?

Comment: there could be endless reasons why this takes a long time. Most likely is their server performance and/or throttling. no easy way to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be a [good web-scraping citizen](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91760/how-to-be-a-good-citizen-when-crawling-web-sites):

- contact the website owners if possible and ask for permission
- set the `User-Agent` header to something that would identify the requests coming from you
- respect the `robots.txt` rules if set

---

If you are or will use `Scrapy`:

- enable the [built-in `AutoThrottle` extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html)
- lower the [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) and increase the [`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay)

Comment: he is not using scrapy

Comment: @WalidSaad oops, good point, fixed that. Thanks for pointing that out.